# sort and group xml by attribute (date) using php

Tags: php, xml, sorting, grouping

I have an xml file containing football results for a month but I need to group them together by date. What would be the best way to sort these out?

```
<match>
    <date>Saturday 18th October 2014</date>
    <game>1</game>
</match>
<match>
    <date>Saturday 18th October 2014</date>
    <game>2</game>
</match>
<match>
    <date>Sunday 19th October 2014</date>
    <game>3</game>
</match>
<match>
    <date>Sunday 19th October 2014</date>
    <game>4</game>
</match>
<match>
    <date>Monday 20th October 2014</date>
    <game>5</game>
</match>
```

So I could output them like:

**Saturday 18th**
Game1
Game2

**Sunday 19th**
Game3
Game4

**Monday 20th**
Game5

Comment: What programming language are you using? Your XML example is also malformed (the `<game>` tags don't end with `</game>`).

Comment: sorry, modified tags. language is PHP

Comment: Have you written any code to try to solve the problem yet?